# Ternary operator in select statement

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ormlite

I am trying to execute a query which has a ternary operator inside a select statement:

```sql
SELECT id, 
       memory_id, 
       CASE 
         WHEN word_to =? THEN word_from 
         ELSE word_to 
       end 
FROM   translations 
WHERE  word_to =? 
       OR word_from =?
```

How can I build such a query using a `QueryBuilder` object?  I tried:

```
public List<Translation> findMeanings(long wordId) {

    try {
        Dao<Translation, Long> translations = getDao(Translation.class);
        QueryBuilder<Translation, Long> queryBuilder = translations.queryBuilder();
        String id = Long.toString(wordId);

        queryBuilder.selectRaw(DBColumns.ID, DBColumns.MEMORY_ID, "CASE WHEN word_to="+id+" THEN word_from ELSE word_to END");
        queryBuilder.where().eq(DBColumns.WORD_TO, id).or().eq(DBColumns.WORD_FROM, id);

        return queryBuilder.query();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Logger.error("db", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return new ArrayList<Translation>();
}
```

But I am getting an exception:

> Could not compile this SELECT_RAW statement since the caller is
>   expecting a SELECT statement.  Check your QueryBuilder methods.

Translation class:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = DatabaseTables.TABLE_TRANSLATIONS)
public class Translation extends BaseEntity {

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignColumnName = DBColumns.ID, columnName = DBColumns.WORD_TO)
    private Word wordTo;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignColumnName = DBColumns.ID)
    private Memory memory;
    //...
```

where BaseEntity is:

```
public class BaseEntity {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, unique = true)
    protected long id; 
    //....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could not compile this SELECT_RAW statement since the caller is expecting a SELECT statement. Check your QueryBuilder methods.

As soon as you call `qb.selectRaw(...)` you will need to use `qb.queryRaw(...)` instead of `query()`.  This is mentioned in the [javadocs for `selectRaw(...)`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html#selectRaw%28java.lang.String...%29):

> Add raw columns or aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, ...) to the query. **This will turn the query into something only suitable for the Dao.queryRaw(String, String...) type of statement.** This can be called multiple times to add more columns to select.

Typically the `selectRaw(...)` is used with some sort of aggregation function like `COUNT()` or `MAX()` and is therefore not compatible with an entity type returned by `query()`.